# Ads are not served to my app even After integrating with MoPub

Tags: android, admob, adsense, google-play, mopub

[image]I have created an account in Mopub and integarted neccessary code to my android app to display a banner ad. After that Demo MoPub ad started displayed.
I think MoPub is like a mediator between publishers and ad networks? correct me if i am wrong.
so i have created account in AdMob as well and successfully integrated it in MoPub(means added that network in MoPub). but still only MoPub Demo ads is getting displayed, what might be the problem?

Comment: Your app could haven't been approved yet on MoPub Marketplace and AdMob. Check their dashboards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MoPub also has a Marketplace feature which is a RTB exchange for mobile that competes against the ad networks you integrate.

Are you able to see any requests and impressions for your account from the AdMob integration?

You should be using your AdMob's 'Ad Unit ID' and not the 'Legacy Publisher ID.' I know it may be confusing as within MoPub's dashboard it mentions to have the 'Publisher ID' but really it should be the 'Ad Unit ID' from AdMob that should be entered.

Please consult this guide for more info: http://help.mopub.com/customer/portal/articles/1376821-how-to-set-up-updated-admob-revenue-reporting

Comment: U mean in set Your Inventory section of MoPub under Publisher Id column i have to enter the 'Ad Unit Id' of AdMob network?

Comment: thanku but I am not able to find Ad Unit Id in Admob. Please can u provide me the link to find it

Comment: I am only seeing Mediation Id as in the snap shot attached. and in the link   http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.in/2013/12/know-your-admob-ad-unit-id.html they have mentioned that before they were using Mediation Id but now google has changed it to AdUnit Id,but for me why Mediation Id is showing, can i use Mediation Id itself? i am fully confused........

Comment: In AdMob dashboard, it is located under the Ad Unit section and referenced to the application you are targeting.  Starts with ca-xxx-.. most likely

Comment: I came to know that still AdMob newer version is not available in all countries. So for me it is showing Mediation Id as in the older version. I am using Mediation Id but still its not showing any ads

Comment: Any resolutions and around Mediation ID?  This is the first I have heard of it.

Comment: now i am using mediation id only its displaying ads